# Checking an isolation amplififer

Tags: amplifier, isolation

[image]

Above is represents an isolation amplifier: http://www.prelectronics.com/pdf/2284-2358-US.pdf

The input comes from a DAQ and output will go to a motor. An isolation amplifier is used as in my illustration.

But when I check GND_input and GND_output with continuity test, they are connected. Arent they supposed to be disconnected electrically?

Comment: From reading the datasheet, I'd expect the same.  Interested in the answer.

Comment: you mean you'd expect they are connected or the other way around?

Comment: Sorry.  I meant I'd expect them to be separate.

Comment: According to the block diagram in the manual (http://www.prelectronics.de/filearkiv/PDF/2200%20series/2284/Manual/2284V104_UK.pdf) this thing actually has three separate grounds that are seperate from one another.  Is it possible You've measure incorrectly?

Comment: Remove all scope probes before you measure, if you have any in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no connection between the input, the output or the supply except as you have connected externally. Here is the internal block diagram from [this](http://www.omniinstruments.co.uk/fileuploader/download/download/?d=0&file=custom%2Fupload%2F2582.pdf) datasheet:

[image]

There are three sets of pins:

a)   9 and 10

b)   5, 6 and 7

c)   1, 2 and 3

There should be no continuity between sets of pins, but there will typically be some measurable impedance between pins within a set. Isolation is provided the dual-secondary supply transformer at the top, and by the internal isolation amplifier in the center (the triangle symbol with a gap).

Comment: There is continuity between (-)input and (-)output in the system. There may be some wrong config and a short between those.

Comment: Are you saying there should be no continuity between pin 1 and pin 6. we use voltage in voltage out.

Comment: @user16307:  Yes, that's what he's saying and also what I would expect from an isolating amplifier.  Is it possible you have something external connected that causes pin 1 to be connected to pin 6, or are you testing with the amplifier completely out of circuit?

Comment: i ll check out thnx

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your image is slightly off..
GND doesn't mean "negative electrode", or "low potential electrode". Instead it means "ground"  - it is an electrode which grounds your device, your casings, shielding etc. Of course, it will be the same at the input and output - it protects your device from electric shock and noise.

Many devices use GND as a reference potential, or "negative electrode" and in those cases "-" is somewhere in the box connected to the GND. Many devices, but not all. What I see from your datasheet is that it has bipolar input/output, so your "-" is separated from GND. You may try to find "+" and "-" ports for both input and output, and confirm that they're isolated.

Comment: No GND is not earth in my case it is 0VDC end

Comment: input goes in as BNC and so the output. And negative ends of these BNCs are connected. checked with continuity test. Which means no isolation to me

Comment: im already checking - input and outputs. GND is not earth in my case it is - input or - output

Comment: "negative ends of BNCs" are cable shields and they should be connected. So, obviously your amplifier has input and output referenced to the GND, making it an asymmetrical port. I assume there is some transformer inside separating input from output but keeping the "negative" side the same.

Comment: you mean there might be some wrong cınnections?